# how can explode my array for multiple languages

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

This is my array:

```
Array ( [TR] => Array ( [name] => sayfa adı [description] =>
sayfa icerigi

[slug] => sayfa linki ) [EN] => Array ( [name_en] => page name [description_en] =>
page information

[slug_en] => page link ) [DE] => Array ( [name_de] => seite name [description_de] =>
seite informationen

[slug_de] => seite link ) )
```

this is my codeigniter insert code:

```
$_INS = array(
            'lang_id' => '?',
            'name' => '?',
            'description' => '?',
            'slug' => '?',
            'page_id' => $insert_id,
            'adding' => $adding,
            'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );
```

and I want to add every array into the DB with a new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple nested foreach with a key modifier to remove the underscore and a batch insert should work:

```
<?php


$array = array(

    'TR' => array (

        'name' => 'stmtA_1',
        'description' => 'stmtA_2',
        'slug' => 'stmtA_3',

    ),

    'EN' => array(

        'name_en' => 'stmtB_1',
        'description_en' => 'stmtB_2',
        'slug_en' => 'stmtB_3',

    ),


);

$insert_id = null;
$adding = null;

$i = 0;

$data = array();

foreach ($array as $lang => $values) {

    $data[$i] = array(
        'page_id' => $insert_id,
        'adding' => $adding,
        'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'lang_id' => $lang
    );

    foreach ($values as $identifier => $value) {

        $key = explode('_', $identifier)[0];

        $data[$i][$key] = $value;

    }

    $i++;

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);

$this->db->insert_batch('my_table', $data);
```